# Javascript 3d-like carousel for complex content

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I have been spending about 7 hours today, trying to:

a) Create my own carousel using intensive javascript and CSS3 features ([see this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/cDqqf6xi))

b) Setup and integrate the [Roundabout plugin from FredHQ](http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout)

c) Setup and integrate the [Cloud Carousel plugin from Professor Cloud](http://www.professorcloud.com/mainsite/carousel.htm)

Both third party solutions were tried because i failed in accomplishing what i wanted by myself. Unfortunately, both solutions do not work the way i would require them to. Both are amazing for displaying images, but i need to show more complex content, a heavily styled DIV with multiple encapsulated DIVs inside, PNGs with transparency, and so forth.

FredHQ's version did not work as it did not scale the content inside my DIVs. Not even the text was scaled, until i removed the font-size parameter, but that is something i need for a proper layout. Cloud's version works with images only.

I have hit a wall and i cannot seem to find any other solution. It seems the word "carousel" is used for slideshows and sliders, so i find hundreds of such solutions, but not one that works like i need it to.

What i need is decreasing opacity on further objects, while the center one is at full opacity. Also further objects should be scaled down by certain scale factors. It does not have to be 3D (not desired, even), but due to the scaling it would look 3d-like.

It does not have to be jQuery, although its probably a good idea if it is.

Does anybody know or can anyone point me to a proper solution?

Comment: I don't know what clowns are downvoting my question but if you are capable of using a search engine you can easily find out that hundreds of questions like this have been submitted to SO in the past: people asking for hints for third-party solutions. There is no need to rudely downvote my well-structured and clearly laid out question that could help others in finding solutions for similar problems, even IF it is a third-party solution they find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at [monete](https://github.com/jackmoore/monte/blob/master/jquery.monte.js)(git), http://www.jacklmoore.com/monte? 184 line. Not sure you'll find something easier to dig into and make it work your way. Hundreds of solutions? So I'll take it you looked at the [cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) as well. That's probably one of the most mature and robust ones out there. You're asking for a lot in your question and these kind of question just wear people out after a while. That's all.

You probably won't find anything that fits your needs EXACTLY and you'll have to roll it yourself or hire someone. If you get something going and come back for specific help, you'll fair much better.

Comment: Thank You for the encouragement. You are right, of course. I just lost my nerve - i think this job is not for me :) Anyway, i guess i figured it out by sticking to it. Not finished, but looks usable now. I will delete this question in a bit. Thank you for your input though!

Comment: ... well, if you have something workable, why not share it? The question in and of itself may not be 'answerable', but there's value in the process and that by itself might be helpful to someone. Often times we just journey on and mark those rabbit holes for other. Your assignment does sound interesting though, hence the "don't give up" and share if you can idea ;-)